# Bubblesort listbox Am i missing something?

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

I want to sort an array[10] with bubblesort and place the unsorted/sorted items in an listbox.
But the array isn't sorted and gives me always the same array of numbers back.

```
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblB.Show();
        lblQ.Hide();

        lbS.Items.Clear();
        lbU.Items.Clear();
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = 10;
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        //listbox fill random
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = r.Next(0, 20);
            lbU.Items.Add(arr[i]);
        }
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < arr.Length)
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = j;
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }    
            }            
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            lbS.Items.Add(arr[i]);
        }

    }
```

Am i missing something here,

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see a call to `lbS.Items.Add` anywhere in your code...

Comment: did you mean `arr[i] < arr[j]` ?

Comment: You are right Jason, i have updated the code.

Comment: Ahh many thanxs Robb, i must have overlooked that.

Comment: Please accept an answer instead of appending "SOLVED."  If those provided are of no help, post one yourself and accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok i've just live chatted with an online "Expert" of Stackoverflow, not sure if just April’s Fools Prank or not;) will post solution right away.

Comment: Not allowed to post on own questions within 8 hours, with rep under 10.

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake in your code that's sorting the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < arr.Length; j++)
   {
       if (arr[i] < arr.Length)
       {
           temp = arr[i];
           arr[i] = j;          // <<-- Mistake here - should be arr[i] = arr[j];
           arr[j] = temp;
       }    
   }            
}
```